# How to post a Comment on a Question or Answer

Tags: support, questions, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

How do you post a comment to a question or answer.  The FAQs suggests 'comments' as a possibility, https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask but there isn't a comments link next to edit or similar.

How do people do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need enough reputation to post comments on questions or answers that are not your own.

The threshold is 50 reputation, as you can see in the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You currently have 21 reputation on Stack Overflow, so 30 more before you can comment on any post.

Also see [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) (community FAQ).